# How can i re-initialize the "i" variable of a loop in the body of the loop?

Tags: java

I'm creating a Java program to assign days in an array to days in a Year so I need to re-initialize my array after seven days basically. How can I re-initialize the "I" variable in my for-loop block.

```
public static void mainAction() {
    for (int i = 0; i < day.numberOfDays; i++) {
        if (day.dayNum == (i + 1)) 
            day.day = DAYS[i];

        if (dayNum == 7) 
            day.day = 1;
    }
}
```

This code keeps on running

Comment: you can use the modulo operator %

Answer (score 1):

```java
result = day.day%7
```

anytime day.day is greater than 7, It does a division and assigns the remainder to result.

`%` is the [modulo](https://www.baeldung.com/modulo-java) operator

Comment: if I may ask, what value are you likening to the variable "result"?

Comment: day.day I didn't understand what Your code is trying to do. THe concept of the modulo is what you need to use, you want the 8 day to automatically be converted to 1. <br>

So  ```8 % 7 ``` evaluates to ```1```. 

I think the right variable might be day.day on line 6.

Comment: okay thanks, i'll try this and give you my feedback, sorry for replying late tho